# practical use of cryptico.js

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, cryptico

Cryptico seems like a super slick RSA encryption library.

cryptico.wwwtyro.net

In regards to JavaScript applications, suppose I want to send data to the client, have them do something to the data, and pass it back. How can I use RSA to ensure that the data clients send back to the server is not tampered with? Since JavaScript is easily reverse-engineered, is there any practical client-side application of cryptico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you - by your example - mean that you want to hide from the user what his client is doing with the data? If so - it's impossible.
You should never trust any data which comes from the client.
If you send encrypted data to the client to process - you must assume that the user knows (or will know if he wants) the encryption key, otherwise it will be impossible to process. In other words there is no secure way to hide from the user what his client processes. Obfuscation - like you've noticed can always be cracked no matter what language you use.

I think that the most common and practical client-side application for this library would be encrypting user's data and sending them to server or vice-versa. There may be some cases you can't use SSL. Moreover, you can make -for example- an encrypted post on facebook which only your friend will be able to decrypt (because he knows the key).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to what you seek (I'm sure there is more than one).  My answer requires two non-conventional approaches to what we call a 'secure connection' and how you receive the 'client code'.

1. You need a physically pre-shared key that initiates a secure connection, and because it's pre-shared it doesn't have to be RSA, which then opens up speed opportunities and higher levels of encryption security for you.
2. Physically pre-share your client code in a similar manner, i.e., download the code from a cd in a magazine or from a pre-paid card sold in a market.  This stops the MITM from sending you tampered and exploited clients, which ssl allows.  Once client is known to be secure, and a real secure connection, mentioned in (1), is established, the client code can be updated.

With the combination of a pre-shared key that develops a secure connection and client code that can pass a checksum, you can achieve what you are after.

Ideally, we should have pre-shared secure connection keys available in the market now, but we don't.  So, for you to do it alone, would require to implement something similar for you website specifically until people in this country get their act together with some real security.  You would have to give them keys over your phone, through the mail, etc.  And your client code would most likely have to be a browser extension to install it due to cross domain security issues.